# What method is recommended after outliers removal?

Tags: predictive-modeling, statistics, data-cleaning, matlab, outlier

I have a data of mice reaction times. In every session, there are some trials in which the mouse "decides of a break" and responds after a long time to these specific trials.
I was thinking of applying outlier removal on my data. and the data does look better (I used a Matlab function which removed all data above of below 3 IQR's above and below median).

After doing that I got a histogram which is more similar to a normal distribution (below an example picture of one of my sessions).

My question is:

> After applying my outlier removal, how should I analyze the remaining data?
>
> Should I consider the Median (together with IQR as standard error mean)?
>
> Or should I consider the mean (together with $ \frac{\sigma}{\sqrt n}$ as standard error mean)?

Remark: I have very little knowledge in statistics, so, I there are mistakes above (for example my standard error mean definition as IQR or $ \frac{\sigma}{\sqrt n}$ is not correct), I would be grateful if you'll let me know.

Thanks!

**Edit**: The purpose of my analysis is to show that under certain conditions, the response times of the mice will be faster then under other conditions.

**fig 1**: Data before outlier removal
[image: before outlier removal]

**fig 2**: Data after outlier removal
[image]

Comment: It depends what you want to find out? 
What is your (statistical) hypothesis you want to test? 

Depending on that, you can choose different tests/models to validate or reject your hypothesis.

Without that information it is not possible to answer your question appropriate.

Comment: @Maeaex1, The purpose of my analysis is to show that under certain conditions, the response times of the mice will be faster then under other conditions.  Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

based on this information I would recommend to use

- [Wilcoxon signed-rank test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilcoxon_signed-rank_test)

or

- [paired Student's t test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Student%27s_t-test)

This depends on your sample size and distribution. To test if your data set is normally distributed you can use the [Jarque-Bera test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jarque%E2%80%93Bera_test).

I didn't work with Matlab yet, but  I guess all the tests should be implemented in Matlab.

From that point you could evaluate the impact of the condition on response time. 
Visualize your data (X on Y) - Scatter plot / Heatmap (if multivariate data).

From here you could start building a model

- starting with linear regression
- going into more advanced models/approaches -- random forests, bootstrapping etc.

**Added**

If you only have binary variables (condition / no condition) - you need to set up dummy variables to perform a regression model (1 / 0) . Data then could look like:

```
 obs  response-time   any_condition  condition_1   condition_2   condition_3
  1   12.54           1              1             0             0
  2   19.34           0              0             0             0
  3   13.32           1              1             1             0
  4   14.7            0              0             0             0
```

If you have multiple different "state" conditions, I would recommend to use a control variable ("any_condition") - to see if conditions (not specifying which, have an impact) on the response time.

I hope that helps.

Comment: OK will try these. Thanks for all the tips!